# GitHub CI/CD cannot deploy to Azure SQL as it cannot add firewall rule due to "deny public network access" being set to Yes

Tags: github, azure-sql-database, cicd

I have an Azure SQL server where I wish to deploy my database via dacpac using GitHub CI/CD. I am using the [Azure SQL Deploy action with Service Principal for Azure login action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-sql-deploy)

Due to policy restrictions on the client side, the "Deny Public Network Access" is always enabled and therefore while deploying even though the service principal login works, the GitHub action is unable to add the IP Address to the firewall rule.

[image]

We are using Self-Hosted GitHub runners. Is there any workaround to deploying the database via CI/CD under such circumstances where we cannot add the firewall rule to whitelist the agent/runners IP Address?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do away with Azure Login action and add self-hosted runner virtual network in the Azure SQL Firewall settings:

1. The Azure Login action attempts to add IP Address of the runner to the Azure SQL Firewall. Hence, this action must not be used. I removed this action and relied on the second step for seamlessly accessing Azure SQL Database instead.
2. The Azure SQL Deploy action requires either above login step or "allow access to azure services" to be turned ON. Both of which were not an option for me. I decided to go with an action that runs sqlpackage.exe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15
3. I am using self-hosted runners which are hosted within the virtual network configured within Azure. However, the point that I had missed was to add the virtual network to the Firewall settings in Azure SQL. Once, I did that, I did not require an explicit login or whitelisting runner ip addresses.

Comment: How did you set up step 3?